# Does @solana/spl-token-registry include SOL token information?

Tags: sol

I'm making a wallet application and using [@solana/spl-token-registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token-registry) to get the icon and name for each SPL token.

My question is does this list include the information for SOL token? Does the SOL token have a mint ID? If not from the spl-token-registry package, where can I get this info (the SOL icon)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not contain SOL, but it has information for wrapped SOL, so you can get your SOL icon from that.

The mint is
So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112

Found in
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/84c566b13e55579aeb291aefa3866faac67e2dfc/token/program/src/native_mint.rs#L7